# Вывести слайдер WordPress без использования плагина

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно для каждой страницы вывести свой слайдер.

Вот сайт на самописном движке: [ссылка](http://www.sanlin-football.kz/astana)

Там есть вывод для каждого города (страницы) вывести тренеров в слайдере.
Как такое реализовать на `WordPress?`

Сверстан  слайдер при помощи `slick slider`. Пример:

```
  <div class="slide-area">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="trainer-1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="trainer-description-area">
                        <div class="trainer-name">  Кузнецов Владимир Владимирович</div>
                        <div class="trainer-experience">
                            <p> Тренер по футболуp</p>
                            <p> Опыт работы: 3 года</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="trainer-description">
                            "Мой принцип по жизни: пришел, увидел,
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Эта вёрстка под slick slider не пойдёт. Вы посмотрите, как на сайте-доноре сделано. Потом запустите скрипт слайдера через wp_enqueue_script(), его css через wp_enqueue_style(), и всё получится.

Comment: Сайт который по ссылке на на WordPress. Это сайт пример на самописном движке. Я пытаюсь сделать на WordPress данный слайдер

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю. Я вам о другом говорю - ваша вёрстка не годится для slick slider, независимо от движка. Вёрстка должна быть такая, как на том сайте, тогда слайдер будет работать. В верстке должны быть ul li с определёнными классами.

Comment: Хорошо. Такой вопрос есть ниже места  проведения тренировок. Как на wordpress для каждого города вывести места проведения тренировок ? Каждый город это отдельная страница. Мест проведения может быть несколько.  Тоесть мне надо както в цикле сделать проверку и вывод...

Comment: Новый вопрос надо задавать отдельно. Но поскольку там ответ всё равно в виде одного комментария, то почитайте вот это - самый простой способ построения цикла в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация происходит через родителя и применяется к вложенным дивам.

По теме, самый простой и быстрый способ:

1. Сперва нужно подключить файлы стилей и скриптов slick-slider через functions.php (возможно, что подключение скриптов и стилей вынесено в отдельный файл).
2. Создать новый тип записей.

Например:

```html
function nvrn_create_partners_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Партнёры', 'Тип записей Партнёры', 'root' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Партнёры', 'Тип записей Партнёры', 'root' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Партнёры', 'root' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Все партнёры', 'root' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Смотреть партнёров', 'root' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить нового партнёра', 'root' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Добавить нового партнёра', 'root' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать партнёра', 'root' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить партнёра', 'root' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Искать партнёра', 'root' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Не найдено', 'root' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'root' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'partners', 'root' ),
        'description' => __( 'Партнёры', 'root' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'genres' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon'=> 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
    );

    register_post_type( 'partners', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'nvrn_create_partners_posttype', 0 );
```

3. В нужном месте написать цикл вывода кастомных типов записей из п.2, применив вёрстку Slick-Slider, где каждая запись - слайд.

Например:

```html
<?php
 $args = array('post_type' => 'partners', 'posts_per_page' => 999,   );
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );?>

 <?php 
 foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
 <a href="<?php the_field('partners_link');?>">
   <img src="<?php the_field('partners_image'); ?>" />               
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </a>
                    
 <?php
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

4. В файле, где у вас находятся скрипты инициализации, инициализировать slick-slider с классом родителя.